# Deriving a curve from datapoints

Tags: c#, math, matlab

I manually adjust the thread count:

```
if (items.Count == 0) { threads = 0; }
else if (items.Count < 1 * hundred) { threads = 1; }
else if (items.Count < 3 * hundred) { threads = 2; }
else if (items.Count < 5 * hundred) { threads = 4; }
else if (items.Count < 10 * hundred) { threads = 8; }
else if (items.Count < 20 * hundred) { threads = 11; }
else if (items.Count < 30 * hundred) { threads = 15; }
else if (items.Count < 50 * hundred) { threads = 30; }
else threads = 40;
```

I need a function that returns the necessary/optimized thread count.

Ok, now forget above. I need a graph curve to plot. I give the coords, function plots the curve. Imagine the point(0,0) and point(5,5) -in (x,y) form. It should be straight line. So then I can measure x for y=3.

What happens if I give the points (0,0), (2,3), (8,10), (15,30) and (30,50). It will be a curve like thing. Now can I calculate x for given y or vice versa?

I think you get the idea. Should I use MathLab or could it be done in C#?

Comment: You should choose the language you prefer. It's too subjective to ask here.

Comment: Why did you put the first part about the threads if you are going to tell me not to think about it?

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for [curve fitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting), or the derivation of a function describing a curve from a set of data points. If you're looking to do this once, from a constant set of data, Matlab would do the job just fine. If you want to do this dynamically, there are libraries and algorithms out there.

Review the Wikipedia article on [linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression). The *least squares* approach mentioned in that article is pretty common. Look around, and you'll find [libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336740) and [code samples](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/QuadraticRegression.aspx) using that approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably make that run faster by reordering the tests (and using nested if).  But that's not a smooth function, there's not likely to be any simpler description.

Or are you trying to find a smooth function that passes near those points?

Comment: Instead of nested if, you could try to put the values (ordered) in a List<int> and do a `BinarySearch`. If the result is < 0 then do the ~result and you will get the next greater element.

Comment: Yes, for 29999 items threads will be 15, for 30000 it will be 30. It should be much smooth.

Comment: @xanatos: That's good if the mapping changes at runtime.  When they're fixed, a binary tree of ifs will have the same complexity as `List.BinarySearch` with a much MUCH lower constant.  And the optimal code depends on the distribution of the input.  I think you'd use a Huffman encoder to figure out the absolute best sequence of tests.

Comment: @Nime: Are you saying you want `nthreads(29999)` to return 15 like the current code, or you want it to be close to 30 to make the curve smooth?

Comment: @Ben if he has const numbers he can use switch/case that will do the same thing.

Comment: @xanatos: No, because `switch` requires exact matches.  A tree of `if` testing inequalities accommodates ranges.

Comment: I want to calculate a better necessary thread count. My code gives a bar graph. @Timvi's excel hack seems nice. If I could calculate the formula (y=0.0056x + 0.5) it would be nice. I'll examine Michael Petrotta's code sample.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a linear regression; you would get something like this:

[image: linear regression]

So I would probably encode it in C# like this:

```
int threads = (int) Math.Ceiling(0.0056*items.Count + 0.5);
```

I used `Math.Ceiling` to ensure that you don’t get 0 when the input isn’t 0. Of course, this function gives you 1 even if the input *is* 0; if that matters, you can always catch that as a special case, or use `Math.Round` instead.

However, this means the number of threads will go up continuously. It will not level out at 40. If that’s what you want, you might need to research different kinds of regression.

Comment: The arctangent function might provide a good shape that approaches a fixed value asymptotically.  Called `atan` in most languages.